# How to get filtered the array in json reponse based on condition check with keys in angular 7

Tags: json, angular, typescript, filter, angular7

I would like to get filterd the particular array alone from the json response when dataID is not matched with the ParentDataID from another array in same json response using typescript feature in Angular 7

```
{ "data":[
    {
       "dataId":"Atlanta",
       "parentDataId":"America"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"Newyork",
       "parentDataId":"America"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"Georgia",
       "parentDataId":"Atlanta"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"South",
       "parentDataId":"Atlanta"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"North",
       "parentDataId":"South"
    }
   ]
}
```

In above response the value of dataId *Newyork* is not matched with any of the parentDataId entire array json response. So Now i want to filtered out only the second array of DataID alone to make new array.

I would like to have this validation in Typescript angular 7

My output is supposed to like below... The DataId does not have the parentDataId

```
[
  {
    "dataId":"Newyork",
    "parentDataId":"America"
  },
  {
     "dataId":"Georgia",
     "parentDataId":"Atlanta"
   },
   {
      "dataId":"North",
      "parentDataId":"South"
     }
]
```

Appreciate the help and response

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough to give you an exact solution. Still your are looking for the `Array.filter()` and `Array.some()` methods. Check out the documentation if you are not familiar with those. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: in your sample data result output is dataId = Newyork, georgea, north are three records you want?

Comment: My intention is I want to get the arrays when dataId does not have parentId in whole JSON response. GaurangDhorda snippet is working fine but it doesn't look backward the response. GaurangDhorda can you help me pls? I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**demo** in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnhjqi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**my solution is like below code snippet. ts**

```
reducedData = [...this.data];

this.data.reduce((c,n,i) => {
   this.data.reduce((d,o, inex) =>  { 
      if ( n.dataId === o.parentDataId){ 
           this.reducedData.splice(i,1, {'dataId': 'removed', parentDataId: 'true'}); 
      } else {
         return o;
      }
    },{});
   return n;
}, {});   

this.reducedData = this.reducedData.filter (value => value.dataId !== 'removed');
```

**html file**

```
<h4> dataId does not have parentId </h4>
<hr>
<pre>
  {{reducedData | json}}
</pre>
```

### EDIT

**If you do not** want to use second object `reducedData`, then below solution is fine to work.. [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59jk9v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**component.ts**

```
this.data.reduce((c,n,i) => {
    this.data.reduce((d,o, inex) =>  { 
      if ( n.dataId === o.parentDataId) {
      this.data[i]['removed'] = "removed";
      } else{
        return o;
      }
    },{});
   return n;
}, {});

this.data = this.data.filter (value => value['removed'] !== 'removed');
```

**component.html**

```
<h4> dataId does not have parentId </h4>
<hr>
<pre>
 {{data |json}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Hi Gaurang, Thanks for your response. Its working fine but getting failed when the 
dataId holds the value of parentDataID which comes first in the JSON response... In this scenario,  it didn't reduce it and it skipped. when JSON response like below the issue is comes. { "dataId":"Georgia", "parentDataId":"Newyork" }, { "dataId":"Newyork", "parentDataId":"Georgia" }, ******* when ParentDataId value is "Newyork"  comes first then following array of dataId calue is "Newyork" the code didnt reduced it. Can you please help me here... Appreciate –

Comment: @user3175778 i have updated my answer... checkout updated answer.

Comment: Hi Gaurang, Can I have an updated slackBlitz link for the fix? the provided one, I couldn't find it. Thanks.

Comment: @user3175778 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnhjqi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts here is updated stackblitz link. as same link is updated in answer too.

Comment: @user3175778 please, `upvote answer`. Now you can upvote answer, because i have upvoted question and you have now required reputation for upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method:

```
let filterKey = 'Atlanta';
const result = data.data.filter(f=> f.parentDataId != filterKey
   && f.dataId != filterKey);
```

An example:

```js
let data = { "data":[
    {
       "dataId":"Atlanta",
       "parentDataId":"America"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"Newyork",
       "parentDataId":"America"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"Georgia",
       "parentDataId":"Atlanta"
    }
   ]
};

let filterKey = 'Atlanta';
const result = data.data.filter(f=> f.parentDataId != filterKey
    && f.dataId != filterKey);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the response. I need exactly opposite. I just updated my question and can you please help me to get it. Thanks and Appreciate

Comment: @user3175778 Atlanta is already mapped into parentDataID so it shouldn't come in response. My reponse should be like beacuse the valueid of dattaId "Newyork"  and "Georgia" is not present in any of the parentDataID value.. right. ?

[
  {
    "dataId":"Newyork",
    "parentDataId":"America"
  },
  {
    "dataId": "Georgia",
    "parentDataId": "Atlanta"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
const data = { "data":[
    {
       "dataId":"Atlanta",
       "parentDataId":"America"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"Newyork",
       "parentDataId":"America"
    },
    {
       "dataId":"Georgia",
       "parentDataId":"Atlanta"
    }
   ]
};

const filterKey = "Newyork"
const matchExist = data.data.some( item => item.parentDataId ===  filterKey && item.dataId === filterKey)
let filteredArray ;
if(!matchExist){
    filteredArray = data.data.find(item => item.dataId === filterKey )
}
```